# Filling available space from nested columns | Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I'm currently working on a bootstrap 4 site that has 2 (2 and 3 in the drawing) components that should fill all remaining space.
I've seen plenty of Questions here with various answers. I've picked the best one and tried to make it fit in my situation. My attempt at that is the following:
https://www.codeply.com/p/sEHcVsMlML

In this codeply the surrounding divs do fill the remaining space. But the nested divs that I actually want to fill the space do not. They're using the same classes so I fail to see why.

The general idea is this:
[image: generalidea]

1,2 and 3 should fill remaining height.

Comment: Hi Tom, sorry but i can't understand your problem, you can put the div title (body content) inside div 2 and 3, but i dont know if thats your question

Comment: @RobertoVargas those titles are just place holders. in the real application these would be intractable components. And these do need to be a seperate div. However my question is: How do I make div 2 and 3 fill the remaining height. specifically without simply setting min-height to 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was working with BS since v2. And can't figure out any solution using only Bootstrap. BS is not omnipotent and in some cases much easier to use additional CSS. Your task solves using `display: grid;`

- More about [Grid basics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)
- More about [grid-template-columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns)
- More about [grid-template-areas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas)

```css
.my-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:  100px 1fr 1fr; /* 3 columns with each width */
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr; /* first row - auto height, second row - all the rest height */
  grid-template-areas: 
    "left top2 top3"
    "left bottom2 bottom3";
  min-height: calc(100vh - 56px); /* 56px is the height of nav */
  /* for acting like .row in .comntainer, optional */
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
.grid-left-1 {
  grid-area: left; /* refers to grid-template-areas of parent */
  background-color: #8ca0ff;
}
.grid-top-2 {
  grid-area: top2;
  background-color: #ffa08c;
}
.grid-bottom-2 {
  grid-area: bottom2;
  background-color: #ffff64;
}
.grid-top-3 {
  grid-area: top3;
  background-color: #8eff8c;
}
.grid-bottom-3 {
  grid-area: bottom3;
  background-color: #a764ff;
}

/* for screen < 510, the example of how you can treat grid on smaller screens*/
@media (max-width: 510px) {
  .my-grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr; 
    grid-template-areas:
      "left left"
      "top2 top3"
      "bottom2 bottom3";
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column vh-100 overflow-hidden">
    <nav class="row navbar navbar-light bg-light navbar-expand px-0 flex-shrink-0">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">App</a>
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">More</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Options</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    
    <div class="my-grid">
      <div class="grid-left-1">1</div>
      <div class="grid-top-2">Some text</div>
      <div class="grid-bottom-2">2</div>
      <div class="grid-top-3">Some text</div>
      <div class="grid-bottom-3">3</div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATED**

Pardon, the one using BS classes. More about [Bootstrap flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/)

```css
.my-height {
  height: calc(100vh - 56px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column vh-100 overflow-hidden">
    <nav class="row navbar navbar-light bg-light navbar-expand px-0 flex-shrink-0">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">I'm 56px height</a>
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">More</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Options</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4 my-height bg-primary  overflow-auto">
        1
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column my-height">
          <div class="bg-secondary">
            Some text
          </div>
          <div class="flex-fill bg-success overflow-auto">
            2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column my-height">
          <div class="bg-secondary">
            Some text
          </div>
          <div class="flex-fill bg-success overflow-auto">
            3
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to work really well! Shame it won't work with default bootstrap classes. This saved the design I was working on tho! thanks (can't award the bounty yet have to wait a bit)

Comment: Excuse me for not believing in BS for the first try. Updated the answer with BS solution, take a look.

Comment: I can't get overflow to work with the second answer. basically I want the divs 2 and 3 to be scroll-able if needed. The "some text" divs don't always have the same height so the vh-100 -56px won't work right?

Comment: 56px - is height of top nav. I hope the top nav will have static height

Comment: yes the top nav has a static height! that's good. Is there a way to solve the scrolling? that would be perfect

Comment: Updated second snippet. Is this your desired result?

Answer (score 1):

You can set negative margin, and add padding to top

```css
.orange{
    background: orange;
    margin-top: -40px;
    padding-top: 50px;
 
}

.pink{
    background: pink;
    margin-top: -40px;
    padding-top: 50px;

}
.title{
    z-index: 1;
    background: red; //I add red to test
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column vh-100 overflow-hidden">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light navbar-expand px-0 flex-shrink-0">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">App</a>
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">More</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Options</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="row flex-grow-1 overflow-hidden">
        <div class="col-2 mh-100 overflow-auto py-2">
            <h6>Sidebar</h6>
            <ul class="nav flex-column bg-info rounded">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class='col mh-100 overflow-auto'>
            <div class='row flex-grow-1'>
                <div class='col mh-100 overflow-auto'>
                    <div class='row flex-shrink-0'>
                        <div class="col title">
                            <h3>Body content</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='row flex-grow-1'>
                        <div class="col pink mh-100 overflow-auto">
                            <h2>This div must fill remaining height</h2>
                            <p>Ethical Kickstarter PBR asymmetrical lo-fi. Dreamcatcher street art Carles, stumptown gluten-free Kickstarter artisan Wes Anderson wolf pug. Godard sustainable you probably haven't heard of them, vegan farm-to-table Williamsburg slow-carb readymade disrupt deep v. Meggings seitan Wes Anderson semiotics, cliche American Apparel whatever. Helvetica cray plaid, vegan brunch Banksy leggings +1 direct trade. Wayfarers codeply PBR selfies. Banh mi McSweeney's Shoreditch selfies, forage fingerstache food truck occupy YOLO Pitchfork fixie iPhone fanny pack art party Portland.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='col mh-100 overflow-auto'>
                    <div class='row flex-shrink-0'>
                        <div class="col title">
                            <h3>Body content</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='row flex-grow-1'>
                        <div class="col orange mh-100 overflow-auto">
                            <h2>This div must fill remaining height</h2>
                            <p>Ethical Kickstarter PBR asymmetrical lo-fi. Dreamcatcher street art Carles, stumptown gluten-free Kickstarter artisan Wes Anderson wolf pug. Godard sustainable you probably haven't heard of them, vegan farm-to-table Williamsburg slow-carb readymade disrupt deep v. Meggings seitan Wes Anderson semiotics, cliche American Apparel whatever. Helvetica cray plaid, vegan brunch Banksy leggings +1 direct trade. Wayfarers codeply PBR selfies. Banh mi McSweeney's Shoreditch selfies, forage fingerstache food truck occupy YOLO Pitchfork fixie iPhone fanny pack art party Portland.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem which is: div 2 and 3 should fill out all remaining space available.